# Remove the column 'impersonating' when user is granted ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have enabled impersonating in my Sonata project.

When a user with role 'ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH' impersonate a user I want the column impersonating to be hidden when he goes to the user list while impersonating. A user can't impersonate while impersonating, an exception will be thrown. But I don't want the exception, I want either a nice message to display that it is not possible but rather hide the column completely so that the links are not even available.

```
if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH')) {
    $listMapper
        ->add('impersonating', 'string',
            ['template' => 'SonataUserBundle:Admin:Field/impersonating.html.twig'])
    ;
}
```

How can I prevent this column from showing when the user has a role 'ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN'? Because this doesn't want to work:

```
if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH') && !$this->isGranted('ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN')) {
```

This does remove the column for the impersonated user, but it also gets removed for the user that has the 'ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH' role but not busy impersonating.

Comment: What you posted looks right.  Might double check to see if it matches your actual code.  Also check the debug toolbar to see what roles your user actually has.  Might be something else preventing the display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You condition and roles are fine, but the `isGranted()` function from  Sonata `admin` class checks the Sonata-Role-Based only (see `RoleSecurityHandler::isGranted()`):

```
public function isGranted(AdminInterface $admin, $attributes, $object = null)
{
    // ...

    foreach ($attributes as $pos => $attribute) {
        $attributes[$pos] = sprintf($this->getBaseRole($admin), $attribute);
    }

    // ...
}

public function getBaseRole(AdminInterface $admin)
{
    return 'ROLE_'.str_replace('.', '_', strtoupper($admin->getCode())).'_%s';
}
```

Therefore, you should check out the system roles into Sonata admin class by using the `@security.authorization_checker` Symfony service instead. For example, after inject it to the admin class, this should work:

```
if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH') 
    && !$this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN')) 
{
```